# Woocommerce Undo Delete Item Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

How can I redirect back to the /cart after I click the 'Undo' link when I delete an item from it?

I am not concerned if the cart is empty or not.  I had to implement a `template_redirect` already, so when a user "removes" an item from the cart it redirects back to the cart rather than the home page.   With:

```
    add_action( 'template_redirect', function( ) {
        $_var = ( $_GET[ 'removed_item' ] ) ?? null;
        //var_dump($_var);
        if( $_var == '1' ){ 
            wp_safe_redirect( '/cart', 301 );
            die();
        }
    } );
```

Can I hook into the same action?  I don't see a query string after clicking the 'Undo' tho...

**EDIT**

I can see where the action is done.  It's in the plugin includes/class-ws-form-handler.php, right around line 536... containing:

```
        // Undo Cart Item
        $cart_item_key = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['undo_item'] );

        WC()->cart->restore_cart_item( $cart_item_key );

        $referer  = wp_get_referer() ? remove_query_arg( array( 'undo_item', '_wpnonce' ), wp_get_referer() ) : wc_get_cart_url();
        wp_safe_redirect( $referer );
        exit;
```

**EDIT 2:**
Adding the following to my redirection above does nothing...

```
// undo the remove, redirect back to cart
if ( ! empty( $_GET['undo_item'] ) && isset( $_GET['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['_wpnonce'], 'woocommerce-cart' ) ) {
    // Undo Cart Item
    $cart_item_key = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['undo_item'] );
    WC()->cart->restore_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
    wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
    exit;
}
```

So, when I `var_dump` `wp_get_referer()` I get back the home page of the site, which is not what I am looking for.   I do not want to modify this file due to that not being that great of an idea... so, how can I just modify the action instead?  The function itself is: `public static function update_cart_action()`

Comment: got it.  may not be pretty, but it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...  I ended up have to do some voodoo to get this to work.

Here is the hook...

```
// undo the remove, redirect back to cart
// check if the cart is updated... if it is, proceed
$_cu = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', true );
if( $_cu ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['undo_item'] ) && isset( $_GET['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['_wpnonce'], 'woocommerce-cart' ) ) {
        // item
        $cart_item_key = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['undo_item'] );
        // Get the cart
        $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        // restore the item
        $woocommerce->cart->restore_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
        // now do the redirect
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

It is applied in the init event